# Таблицы базы данных

Tags: sql, база-данных

У меня такой вопрос. Допустим, создается база данных библиотеки, у нас имеется множество жанров. Следовательно имеются таблицы книга(соответственно с id, названием, автором и жанром) и жанр. Одна книга может относиться сразу к нескольким жанрам(допустим больше 5), как в концептуальной модели это отобразить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Это отношение Многие-ко-многим (Many-to-many).

Answer (score 2):

Это известная проблема с хранением в реляционной базе отношений "многие ко многим" (многие жанры к многим книгам)

Предлагаю решить её так:

у Вас будет таблица книг `books` (из описания книги при этом убираем идентификатор жанра), таблица жанров `genres` и таблица отношений между книгами и жанрами `books_to_genres`.

Последняя таблица содержит пары "id книги (book_id)" - "id жанра (genre_id)". Именно эта пара является в ней PK (primary key)

Теперь у нас есть возможность делать выборку по жанрам (что то вроде select * from books where books.id in (select book_id from books_to_genres where genre_id=12)

А вот таким запросом можно вытащить названия всех книг с соответсвующими жанрами:

```
    select books.id, books.title, books.author, 
    tgenre=(select STRING_AGG(genre, ', ') from genres where id in 
    (select genre_id from books_to_genres where book_id=books.id))  
    from books
```

Результат получается примерно таким:

```
    1   Воспламеняющая взглядом    Стивен Кинг         Детектив, Фантастика, Ужасы
    2   Дверь в лето               Роберт Хайнлайн     Фантастика
```

Здесь используется функция STRING_AGG() котрая преобразует список в подзапросе в строку, разделенную пробелами. Если в том SQL, с котрым Вы работаете, этой фугкции нет - существует очень похожее решение с использованием `FOR XML PATH ('')`.